# C#: Attempting to make extremely simple login system for two users

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I'm currently trying to use Visual Studio 2013 with C#, to make an extremely simple login system. It is designed for two users. One of these is simply called user and when their username and password is entered successfully the program opens a form called NewBooking. The second user is called manager and after they have entered their credentials a form called manager should be opened. This is the code I have made so far:

```
public partial class login : Form
{
    Thread th;

    public login()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnLogIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string a = txtUsername.Text;
        string b = txtPassword.Text;

        if (a == "user")
        {
            if (b == "password")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Welcome User");

                this.Close();

                th = new Thread(opennewform);
                th.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
                th.Start();
            }
            if (a == "manager")
            {
                if (b == "managerpassword")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Welcome Manager");

                    this.Close();

                    th = new Thread(openmanagerform);
                    th.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
                    th.Start();
                }
            }
            else
              MessageBox.Show("Password Incorrect ,Try Again"); 
        } 
        else
          MessageBox.Show("Username Incorrect ,Try Again");
    }

    private void openmanagerform(object obj)
    {
        Application.Run(new manager());
    }

    private void opennewform(object obj)
    {
        Application.Run(new NewBooking());
    }
}
```

Currently the user account can login and open their associated form. When I try to login as manager the program just says that the username and password are incorrect. How can I change the code so that rather than doing this the program opens the manager form.

Necessary postscript: Yes I know this is not how you would implement a login system in an actual program. Please just let me know if it's possible to alter my code so it will do as I intend it to.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to learn how `if`, `else if` and `else` work.

Comment: Take a careful look at where you've got your braces in your `if` statements.  Currently you say "if a is equal to user then .... if a is equal to manager" - obviously the second one can never be true.

Comment: Rule #1 in programming: Line up your opening/closing braces, it helps you spot problems

Comment: On another note, learn to use the debugger and step through, you will quickly solve most of your own problems. because in your code if a was "manager" it would never be hit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have

```
if (a == "manager")
```

inside the if-block:

```
if (a == "user")
```

So essentially the `if (a == "manager")` will always evaluate to false (hence never executes.

If you look at it from the top level perspective, your code looks like this:

```
if (a == "user")
{
    // ... bunch of code

    if (a == "manager")  // <-- never gonna be true!
    { }
}
```

Just pull out the `if (a == "manager")` code block and make it come after the other if-block.

Alternatively, you could rewrite your code to use a `switch` statement instead of successive `if` statements:

```
switch(a)
{
    case "user":
        // code here
        break;
    case "manager":
        // code here
        break;
}
```

Personally, I'd say that the `switch` is much easier to read and manage.

Comment: Could you clarify the exact lines I'd have to change to fix this?

Comment: Well from just looking, I can see you are testing if (a == "user")
inside that brackets your testing if (a == "manager")

Comment: Look at the third code sample in code4life's answer

Comment: Where do I need to put manager to make it true though?